# lsyncd - Sync immediately when source is shared folder

Tags: shared-folders, rsync

I have a Ubuntu 12.10 guest that is running in VMware Workstation on a Windows 7 host.

I have created a shared folder so that Ubuntu can see a folder that lives on my Windows 7 host. I then set it up so that every time Ubuntu boots, the shared folder will be mounted under `/files`.

So far, everything works well. However, I created a second folder called `/files2` and wish to use `lsyncd` to sync `/files` to `/files2`.

- lsyncd was installed using `sudo apt-get install lsyncd`.
- After installation, I created `/etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.conf.lua`.

This is my configuration file (`etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.conf.lua`)

```
sync {
    default.rsync,
    source    = "/www",
    target    = "/www2",
    rsyncOpts = "-ltuspogX",
    delay=0
}
```

The problem is that the sync never seems to happen, that is even if I restart or start/stop `lsyncd`.

Finally, if I ever create a file in the shared folder on the host machine (windows 7), I can see it in `/files`, but it never gets synced to `/files2`.

I need to get `lsyncd` to sync when I create/modify/delete folders in `/files` in my Ubuntu guest or Windows.

Is there anything in my configuration that I have missed to cause the sync to not work?

Answer (score 1):

`rsyncOpts` was depreciated you need to use the `rsync {}` structure in the lua config file

This link should help: https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd/wiki/Lsyncd%202.1.x%20%E2%80%96%20Layer%204%20Config%20%E2%80%96%20Default%20Behavior

Look at the "default.rsync" section, there's some example code and below it a list of the available rsync options.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @papukaija the answer is there, the link is just a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration

```
settings {
    logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd.log",
    statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd-status.log",
    statusInterval = 20,
    nodaemon = true
}
sync {
   default.rsync,
   source="/files1/",
   target="/files2/",
   rsync = {
     archive = true,
     compress = true,
     whole_file = false,
     _extra = { "-ltuspogX" },
     verbose = true
   },
   delay=5,
   log=all,
}
```